Can any pulse modulation system be multibit without varying amplitude?
There are multiple types of analog pulse modulation such as PWM pulse width modulation, PDM pulse density modulation, PPM pulse position modulation.
Is it possible to make any of the above pulse modulation techniques multibit without making the amplitude of individual pulses variable?
By multibit I mean inceasing the bits to 2 or more to allow superior TPDF dither which requires atleast 2 bits to work. To me these pulse modulation techniques seem like they are all inherently limited to simple 1 bit ON OFF operation unless the amplitude become variable too.

I'm not sure how you come to the conclusion that that these modulations can only be 1 bit? That seems to be contrary to what you describe in the first paragraph, and also wrong?

If it is wrong, please describe how its wrong. How can any pulse modulation technique with only 2 levels of amplitude, OFF zero current and ON pulse peak current be able to use triangular probability density funcion dither which requires atleast 2 bits?

Literally as you describe in your first paragraph! The information is not in the height of the amplitude, at all, but when it's on (PPM), for how long it's on (PWM), how often it is on (PDM)… (have you tried wikipedia on these terms?)

I have read the wikipedia articles on these many times over the span of 7 years. I think I start to understand how PPM modulation can be multibit without changing amplitude but "how often it is on (PDM)" and "how long it's on (PWM)" all sound to me like factors that are entirely dependent on frequency, not bit depth.

what does frequency have to do with that? (You seem to have a misunderstanding, but by not explaining why you claim that, it's hard to help you)

Also, your usage of "analog" in your first sentence is not very sensible when you want to talk about bitdepth, by the way.

I understand the confusion. I plan to make a DAC so its both digital and analog device. As for what frequency has to do with how often PDM pulses, everything. How often PDM pulses is literally the pulse frequency. How often PWM switches is the switching frequency.

but the frequency of the pulses doesn't matter to the information. Their desity does. PDM doesn't even care whether your pulses come at a regular interval at all – and, very often, they don't! So, you need to revisit PDM, I'm afraid. Same for PWM: the width of the pulse carries the information, the frequency of the pulses is totally irrelevant to the information transported!

PDM and PWM both support multiple bits, as multiple bits are achieved by how many states (or symbols) we are able to encode.
For example here is a mapping for 2 bit PDM (4 symbols)

For PDM we vary the density of fixed width pulses within the single symbol duration. With PWM we vary the width of a single pulse within the single symbol duration.
Below shows a 1st order Delta Sigma DAC which is a PDM modulator. When configured with an 8 bit input and 9 bit accumulator for example, the output will provide density patterns supporting $2^8$ different levels when averaged and thus requires a 256 bit stream to complete each symbol. This is used to implement a Digital to Analog converter.

